# Como detectar um texto específico em uma string

Tags: python-3.x

Eu quero fazer um programa que detecte se tem um "texto" em específico, no input digitado pelo usuário.

Nesse exemplo, o "texto": 100

Quero que ele detecte esse 100(independente da posição) no input. Exemplo: teste100 ou 100teste

Estou querendo desenvolver esse programa, para excluir arquivos. Vamos supor que eu tenho os arquivos: "t100.txt", "a100.txt", "b100.txt". Eu quero que ele exclua cada arquivo que conter "100" no título.

```
import os 

#Arquivos
a1 = open('t100.txt', 'r+')
a2 = open('a100.txt', 'r+')
a3 = open('b100.txt', 'r+')

string = input('Você deseja excluir todos os arquivos que contém qual string: ')

if string[] == '100':
    print("Removendo os arquivos que contém '100' no título")
    os.remove()
else:
    print("Não há arquivos que contém '100' no título")
```

Comment: No titulo ou no nome do arquivo ?

Comment: Nome do arquivo, acabei confundindo :x

Answer (score 1):

Seu código não fez muito sentido, mesmo achando ele nem era para fazer mesmo, seria só para tentar ilustrar. Uma solução possível, visto que está tabalhando com arquivos é utilizar a função `glob.glob` para pegar os arquivos que obedecem uma determinada expressão regular. Com a expressão regular é possível verificar se determinado valor existe no nome do arquivo.

Por exemplo, se você precisa buscar todos os varquivos que possuem o número 100 no nome, dentro do diretório `arquivos`, você pode fazer:

```
from os import remove
from glob import glob

for arquivo in glob('arquivos/.*100.*'):
    remove(arquivo)
```

Outra solução, se utilizar Python 3.4+, é utilizar o pacote `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path

for arquivo in Path('arquivos').glob('.*100.*'):
    arquivo.unlink()
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, o meu objetivo era tentar ilustrar.

Comment: Criei uma pasta com o nome "arquivos" na área de trabalho, e coloquei alguns arquivos com "100" no nome do arquivo. Rodei o programa, ele não excluiu os arquivos.

Comment: Mas seu script está rodando na área de trabalho?

Comment: Sim, eu cloquei pra rodar na área de trabalho, porque é onde a pasta está. Mas, depois, coloquei na pasta o script, e mesmo assim, não funcionou. Usei a segunda solução(python 3.4).

Comment: Tente colocar `./arquivos`

Comment: Não funcionou. Caso acrescente algo, estou usando windows 7.